# The SQL statement to check "~ is in or not"

Tags: mysql, sql, selection, mariadb

I'd like make the right table from the left table on MySQL.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nchSi.png)

```
SELECT A.id AS id, B.name AS name, A.name as loca FROM tst A, tst B WHERE A.id = B.loca;
```

But, This can not select the rows which location field is not in id field.
To select rows which don't need to replace location name,
How can I make it?
I need your hint.

Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  l1.id,
  coalesce(l2.name, l1.loca) as loca
from
  loca l1 left outer join
  loca l2
    on (l1.loca = l2.id);

|----+----------|
| id |   loca   |
|----+----------|
| 1  | ROOM1    |
| 2  | desk 1   |
| 3  | desk 1   |
| 4  | ROOM2    |
| 5  | desk 2   |
| 6  | case     |
| 7  | drawer 1 |
| 8  | ROOM3    |
|----+----------|
```

Given this table definition:

```
create temp table loca (
  id text,
  name text,
  loca text
);

insert into loca values
(1, 'desk 1',   'ROOM1'), 
(2, 'drawer 1', '1'),     
(3, 'drawer 2', '1'),     
(4, 'desk 2',   'ROOM2'), 
(5, 'case',     '4'),     
(6, 'redpen',   '5'),     
(7, 'blkpen',   '2'),     
(8, 'printer',  'ROOM3');
```